# SQL: Condition to fetch records when date is is a particular month or is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table t1

```
name  Date1
    a    2021-01-24
    b    2021-07-18
    c    2021-07-07
    d    2021-05-20
    e    NULL
    F    NULL
    g    2021-08-01
```

and so on.

I need the data for months 5 to 8 and data where Date1 is NULL

Query:

```
select Date1, name
from t1
where (month(Date1) <= 8 and month(Date1)>=5) or (month(Date1)=null)
```

The problem with this query is that I am not getting any rows where Date1 is NULL .

Can anyone please help

Comment: Side note: it's best not to use functions on dates, better to use a range filter `Date1 >=20210501 AND Date1 < 20210901`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Date1 is null` to check if the column is null:

```
select Date1, name
from t1
where (month(Date1) <= 8 and month(Date1)>=5) or (Date1 is null)
```